# State prediction of how long someone sleeps using neural nets

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, markov-process, recurrent-neural-network

I have over hundred thousands of datapoints on how long individual people sleep. I also have information about how soft their beds are, their income, stress levels etc.

At first I want to predicted how long people sleep, using the other features.
For example, one features set would be (not scaled or normalized):

**income: 100000**

**stress: 0.5**

**smoker: 1**

**diabetes: 0**

and so on...

And my target would be:

**total_hours_slept: 8**

There is a problem: Say every hour chronogically during when someone is asleep, I want to predict again how much total sleep they will have and this number will go up:

Example: On the first observation when I've slept for 0 hours, Im predicted to have 7 hours remaining for a total of 7 hours slept. If you observe me again after I have been sleeping for 7 hours, I'm might have on average 1 hour remaining, because I fulfilled the condition that I didn't wake up after hours 0,1,2,3,5,6,7 therefore I'm predicted to sleep for a total of 8 hours. In other words: The chance of transitioning from asleep to awake increases the longer one has been asleep.

Therefore it is important to know how long someone has been sleeping to guess how long they will sleep in total (a bias), which If I want to eliminate I need to incorporate my question. So now it is: How long will a person sleep if they have already slept for X hours.

I know that an RNN is able to learn and infer these types of conditions. The problem is that I don't see how I can test the accuracy of my model if it only has data on **total_hours_slept** and does not have **already_been_asleep_for**. I would guess that I need to augment the data to include **already_been_asleep_for**, but I dont see how I can do that.

Comment: Your description is a little hard to follow. Predicting how long someone will sleep sounds like a regression problem, but "conditional probability" makes it sound like you're treating it as a binary state. Can you edit your post to clarify this, perhaps posting a small snippet of your data?

Comment: I have edited for a bit more clarification. Let me know if it's still not clear enough!